# wix install xml file, edit file and copy to another location

Tags: wix

I am trying to install a XML file(Tomcat context file) and copy the file to another location inside Tomcat\config\Catalina\ using WiX. 
Before copying the file to Tomcat, I want to edit some values in the Context xml. Here, I have modified the xml using the tag  from WixUtilExtension.

**Below is what I have Done:**

```
    <SetProperty Id="CopyLocation" Value="[%CATALINA_HOME]\conf\Catalina\" Before="AppSearch" Sequence="execute"/>     
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
        <Directory Id="dirA99A3925C98F7E949CF98F783959A0E0" Name="MyInstallFolder">
            <Component Id="cmp318E197D1FB960F5622BEB6879276359" Guid="{FFF02817-FA29-40B7-927A-E943C08A8774}">
              <File Id="fil6674D3AD50416393E3C992B211173485" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.installfolder)\MyContext.xml" />          

                 <util:XmlFile Id="DocBase" Action="setValue" Permanent="yes" File="[#fil6674D3AD50416393E3C992B211173485]"
            ElementPath="//Context" Name="docBase"
            Value="[INSTALLDIR]InstallFolder" SelectionLanguage="XPath" Sequence="1"/>

              <CopyFile Id="Copy_File" DestinationProperty="CopyLocation" DestinationName="MyContext.xml" FileId="fil6674D3AD50416393E3C992B211173485"/>          
            </Component>
        </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

**Below is the XML Sample:**

```
    <Context path="/XERService" docBase="NoValue">
    </Context>
```

The issue is that I am able to modify the file that is installed to the installation path but the file which is copied to the Tomcat doesnot have the changes.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the default sequence for the DuplicateFiles action (the MSI action that maps to [CopyFile](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/copyfile.html)) happens before the SchedXmlFiles action. You should be able to override this by specifying the following:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SchedXmlFile" Before="DuplicateFiles" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```